# Connection to Azure DevOps from Power BI Desktop

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to get a connection from Power BI desktop and my organization's Azure DevOps.
URL is currently : [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D)

In Power BI, I use the "Azure DevOps Server (Boards only)" type of data connection.

I'm prompted with this :

[image: Power BI connector]

After entering "organization" in "collection URL" text box, and "project" in "Team project" text box, I got this error :

[image: Connection Error]

Do you have any suggestions? Could it be Firewall?

Comment: Do you check all prerequisites??

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

From the Organization URL, you are using the Azure Devops Service.

You need to select the `Azure Devops (Boards only)` option in PowerBI Desktop. This option is for Azure Devops Service.

[image]

The `Azure Devops Server(Boards Only)`option  is used for Azure Devops Server instead of Azure Devops Service.  I ran into the same issue when I used this option.

Then you could input the `organizaiton name` in `Organization Box` and the `Project Name` in `Team Project Box`. It can be able to work.